# split sentences of the text dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I have a text file with 30,000 sentences. How can I pad each sentence of this file with start and end symbols such as (s) and (/s) by **Python**?

A part of data is the following:
The jury further said in term-end presentments that the City Executive Committee , which had over-all charge of the election , `` deserves the praise and thanks of the City of Atlanta '' for the manner in which the election was conducted .

Comment: Open the text file, get lines in a list with `readlines()` on the file object, add the desired padding string with each item of the list, write them back to another file !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# open the input file for reading and create a new output file for writing
readfile = open('input.txt', 'r')
writefile = open('newfile.txt', 'w')

# read each line in the input file
for line in readfile:

    # remove the trailing carriage return
    line = line.strip()

    # write the prefix symbol, the input line, the postfix symbol,
    # and a carriage return to the output file
    writefile.write('(s)' + line + '(/s)' + '\n')
```

Of course this assumes that each line is a sentence.

If a line can have more than one sentence, or if a sentence can span over multiple lines, it gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great and complete answer. you solved my question.